# New Terminal At Folder service in El Capitan doesn't use my Terminal profile settings

Tags: terminal, finder, macos

I have my Terminal preferences set to use the "Pro" profile. When I launch a Terminal session from the dock, it uses the "Pro" profile (black background). However when I launch a Terminal session from "Services -> New Terminal at Folder" in Finder, it uses the "Basic" profile (white background). How can I set it to always use the "Pro" profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After launching Terminal.app the active profile of the shell  window is determined by the settings chosen in: Preferences > General > On startup open...

The profile of the next Terminal window opened or the one launched by *Services -> New Terminal at Folder* uses a default profile which can be configured here: Preferences > Profiles > Text: choose a profile in the left pane and hit the default button at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks. It took me ages to find this button on a new Apple computer. I thought I was going crazy, because I did have set my profile as the default for new windows and tabs (from an existing window), but new windows from the dock would still show me the ugly and useless default profile. Now it works like it should!